# Conplex analysis showing normal

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the family of functions $f_n(z)=z^n,n\geq 1$ is normal in $D(0;1)$ but not in any region which contains a point on the unit circle.

I tried to show that the spherical derivatives of $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded so that I can use Marty's theorem but I could not do it as $n$ goes to infinity. Is there another way, or is it easy to show this in some way I cannot see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f_n(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in D(0;1)$. If a sequence of holomorphic functions is uniformly bounded on compact subsets then it a  normal family. (This is Montel's Theorem)

Now suppose we include  a point $c$ on the boundary. Consider $\{z_1,z_2,... \} \cup \{c\}$ where $(z_k)$ is a sequence in the domain such that  $|z_k| <1$ and $z_k \to z$. If there is a subsequence of $(f_n)$ which converges uniformly on compact subsets of our new domain then the limit would be $0$ at each of the points $z_k$ but $|f_n(c)|=1$ for all $n$ . Hence the limit function is not even continuous. This proves that the family is not normal.

Answer (score 1):

Marty's theorem only requires the spherical derivatives to be locally uniformly bounded,
and this is easy to prove: consider a disc of radius $r<1$. Then, on that disc,

$$\mu(f_n)=\frac{2|nz^{n-1}|}{1+|z^n|^2}\le 2\frac{nr^{n-1}}{1+r^{2n}}\to 0$$

However, we can prove a stronger statement using Montel's theorem, which considers normality in the space of holomorphic functions (while Marty's theorem is about normality inside the space of meromorphic functions).

Montel's Theorem: a family of functions is normal iff it is locally uniformly bounded.

On $D(0;1)$ it is easy to see that $|f_n|$ is uniformly bounded (and thus locally un. bounded).

Every region containing a point on the unit circle will also contain a point $z$ outside the closed unit disc: since $|f_n(z)|\to \infty$, the family is not locally uniformly bounded and thus it is not normal.

Actually, Montel's theorem shows that a stronger statement is true: $\{f_n(z)=z^n\}$ is normal (inside the holomorphic functions) iff the region is contained in the unit disc.